# Remove # from URL after navigating in the page?

Tags: .htaccess, url, reveal.js

I have a website (one page moving in horizontal and vertical ways) that uses reveal.js and I have some sections. There's a menu to navigate to each "screen". The problem is with url address. For moving to sections with menu I need to gave hrefs like #/1 (first section), #/2 (second section) etc.

What I'm looking for is some rule in htaccess that will MASK (not redirect because then i will go nowhere from main section) for example this url `http://www.domain.pl/index.html#/1` after clicking first position in nav to main domain `http://www.domain.pl/index.html`

Comment: What does mask mean in this context? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: `#` hash is client side, so no, you can't rewrite it as it doesn't affect the server either at least not with `.htaccess` but perhaps there is a way with javascript.

Comment: Can you say some more about this way with javascript?